# Can a Prime Minister be appointed if they do not have a seat in the Parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, parliament, prime-minister

On December 12, 2019, UK will hold a general election. As stated in Wikipedia's [2019 United Kingdom general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_United_Kingdom_general_election):

> The election is to be contested under the same boundaries for 650 constituencies that have been used since the 2010 general election

This means that the 650 members of the Parliament are elected individually, each one in a different constituency.

[Some polls](https://twitter.com/electo_mania/status/1204679620802547718) show that the current primer minister, Boris Johnson, leader of the Conservatives, does not have his seat granted in Uxbridge and South Ruislip, the constituency he is running for:

> [image]

Wikipedia on [Prime Minister of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_the_United_Kingdom#Parliament_Act_and_the_premiership) states:

> The Office of the Prime Minister is not established by any statute or constitutional document but exists only by long-established convention, whereby the reigning Monarch appoints as Prime Minister the person most likely to command the confidence of the House of Commons; this individual is typically the leader of the political party or coalition of parties that holds the largest number of seats in that chamber.

However, I cannot find a reference on whether the Prime Minister needs to have a seat in the Parliament. Is there any rule on that?

Comment: Related questions are https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47816/10121 , https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8248/10121 , https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/19855/10121 , and https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8238/10121 .

Answer (score 5):

Legally, no. By convention, yes, although not necessarily at the moment of being appointed. Consider the case of [Douglas-Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alec_Douglas-Home#Prime_Minister_(1963%E2%80%9364)), who was a member of the House of Lords when he was appointed Prime Minister. He disclaimed his peerage and contested a by-election to enter the Commons.

So if the Conservatives win a majority but Johnson loses his seat, it would not be unprecedented for one of his colleagues in a very safe seat to take the Chiltern Hundreds and trigger a by-election which Johnson could contest.

Comment: I assume well in that 'taking the Chiltern Hundreds' referers to _the legal fiction used to resign from the House of Commons_ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiltern_Hundreds))?

Comment: @fedorqui correct.

Comment: So based on your answer: it would not be possible and would need to have Boris Johnson elected in another constituency? Would that mean waiting several weeks due to all the bureaucracy attached to organising a by-election, so in the meanwhile the prime minister wouldn't be appointed?

Comment: @fedorqui, he would continue as PM (although I'm not sure what would happen to Prime Minister's Questions - probably another minister would take his place in the interim). If he lost a second by-election in a seat that was supposed to be safe, I would expect a motion of no confidence (internally in the party, in the House of Commons, or both).

Comment: Ah right because Boris Johnson is the current PM and will remain as that until a new one is appointed. So what about more generally: what if Labs won and Corbyn didn't have a seat? (which was a bit more on my question, to check how this works in theory, not in this specific case). Thanks for your feedback, I know I am asking a lot in comments :D

Comment: @fedorqui, as an additional complication, party rules are also relevant. I'd have to find the Labour rules, because they have a more defined fallback system than the Tories and it *might* say that in that scenario the deputy party leader would take over. It is worth noting that the Cabinet Manual does say that the PM is *usually* the leader of the largest party in the government; in principle the PM could be a member of a smaller party who wasn't the leader of that party, or even an independent in an unusual coalition.

Comment: It's been suggested that if an MP were to vacate a seat for the PM, that MP would be given a life peerage as a reward. This would automatically disqualify them as an MP, as you can't be a member of both the House of Lords and the Commons at the same time.

Comment: So sad to have found out that the Crown Steward and Bailiff of the Chiltern Hundreds is no longer the guy from Sinn Féin … that was such an amusing side-effect of this legal fiction.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff, the current Steward of the Chiltern Hundreds is an MP who was nominated to a life peerage in Theresa May's resignation honours. Don't ask me why it was necessary for him to take the Hundreds, because I don't know.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff but is the Chiltern Hundreds title available for just a person at any given time or can many share it? I mean: what if multiple MPs want to resign at the same time?

Comment: @fedorqui: people can be appointed en masse; according to [the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Stewards_of_the_Chiltern_Hundreds), on 17 Dec 1985, 8 MPs were appointed at once. It's not clear if they were appointed to the role together, or one after the other. Either way, the effect is the same.

Comment: @fedorqui: [BBC suggests](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/82115.stm) that they are appointed once at a time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Alec Douglas-Home avoided the PMQs issue by proroguing Parliament for the duration of the period while he was disclaiming his peerage and fighting his by-election.  I suspect these days, the Supreme Court wouldn't allow that.